# PhpAmqpLib: Uncaught exception 'ErrorException' with message 'fwrite(): send of 19 bytes failed with errno=104 Connection reset by peer'

Tags: php, symfony, debian, rabbitmq

My RabbitMQ consumer is crashing after processing some messages with the following error:

> /usr/bin/php /var/www/mydomain/integration.mydomain.com/current/app/console rabbitmq:consumer -w segment --env=prod
>
> [PhpAmqpLib\Exception\AMQPRuntimeException]
>     Invalid frame type 65
>
> rabbitmq:consumer [-m|--messages [MESSAGES]] [-r|--route [ROUTE]] [-l|--memory-limit [MEMORY-LIMIT]] [-d|--debug] [-w|--without-signals] [-h|--help] [-q|--quiet] [-v|vv|vvv|--verbose] [-V|--version] [--ansi] [--no-ansi] [-n|--no-interaction] [-s|--shell] [--process-isolation] [-e|--env ENV] [--no-debug] [--]
>
> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'ErrorException' with message 'fwrite(): send of 19 bytes failed with errno=104 Connection reset by peer' in /var/www/mydomain/integration.mydomain.com/shared/vendor/php-amqplib/php-amqplib/PhpAmqpLib/Wire/IO/StreamIO.php:281
>   Stack trace:
>   0 [internal function]: PhpAmqpLib\Wire\IO\StreamIO->error_handler(8, 'fwrite(): send ...', '/var/www/tracti...', 281, Array)
>   1 /var/www/mydomain/integration.mydomain.com/shared/vendor/php-amqplib/php-amqplib/PhpAmqpLib/Wire/IO/StreamIO.php(281): fwrite(Resource id #809, '\x01\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\v\x00\x14\x00(\x00\x00\x00\x00...', 8192)
>   2 /var/www/mydomain/integration.mydomain.com/shared/vendor/php-amqplib/php-amqplib/PhpAmqpLib/Connection/AbstractConnection.php(327): PhpAmqpLib\Wire\IO\StreamIO->write('\x01\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\v\x00\x14\x00(\x00\x00\x00\x00...')
>   3 /var/www/mydomain/integration.mydomain.com/shared/vendor/php-amqplib/php-amqplib/PhpAmqpLib/Connection/AbstractConnection.php(448): PhpAmqpLib\Connect in /var/www/mydomain/integration.mydomain.com/shared/vendor/php-amqplib/php-amqplib/PhpAmqpLib/Wire/IO/StreamIO.php on line 281

The current queue has about 30k messages, but I moved all messages to a new one and try again with an empty queue and the error persist.

I have enough free memory (180GB free ram memory)

The consumer crash after processing some messages, it usually takes 30s before crashing.

There is only one consumer for this queue.

RabbitMQ configuration is the default.

I'm using Symfony2 and mongodb and Debian Jessie.

Another clue, it always crash after 27 or 28 seconds.

Any idea about it?

Thanks.

Comment: any solution? I am also experiencing this issue and others are too. https://github.com/php-amqplib/php-amqplib/issues/398

Comment: Possibly related to hearbeat, see https://github.com/php-amqplib/php-amqplib/issues/437

Answer (score 2):

The best way would be to see what is in the logs of rabbitmq server if you have access to it.

Other than that judging by the fact that it happens on average when the script reaches 30secs execution time I'd like to suggest you to control the amount of messages for your client as it looks like it chokes on the number of messages from your broker.

In terms of phpamqplib try to do the following right after declaring your queue:

```
$channel->basic_qos(null, 10, null);
```

and see if it works. If it does not I believe the network settings/environment is the issue.

Comment: I tried this option. It doesn't solve the problem, but it avoids the worker to crash because 10 messages are reached before 30s. It looks like a network setting as you said but can't find where. Thanks.